# Puppet - How to use $facts['name'] in notify {}

Tags: puppet

## Question

How I can use $facts['fact name'] in notify?

## Issue

The code below is OK.

```
$virt = $facts['virtual']
notify { "I'm using a value !${virt}! ": }
```

Notice: I'm using a value !vmware!

However, the code below shows (it looks) all the facts.

```
notify { "I'm using a value $facts['virtual'] ": }
```

Notice: I'm using a value {architecture => amd64, augeas => {version => 1.4.0}, augeasversion => 1.4.0, bios_release_date => 09/30/2014, bios_vendor => Phoenix Technologies LTD, bios_version => 6.00, blockdevice_fd0_size => 0, blockdevice_sda_model => Virtual disk, blockdevice_sda_size => 107374182400, blockdevice_sda_vendor => VMware, blockdevice_sdb_model => Virtual disk, blockdevice_sdb_size => 536870912000, blockdevice_sdb_vendor => VMware, blockdevice_sr0_model => VMware IDE CDR10, blockdevice_sr0_size => 1073741312, blockdevice_sr0_vendor => NECVMWar, blockdevices => fd0,sda,sdb,sr0, boardmanufacturer => Intel Corporation, boardproductname => 440BX Desktop Reference Platform, chassisassettag => No A ...... (a lot)

Kindly help oo get the same result as in the first, but not using ${::virtual} but using $facts['virtual'].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it like this:

```
notify { "I'm using a value ${facts['virtual']}": }
```

Comment: To elaborate on this answer, you must place braces around hash lookups when interpolating within a string.